# Nifi Getfile Unzip and Putfile

Tags: apache-nifi

How to fetch files and unzip and save them in separate folders under the output folder in Nifi. Eg:100.zip (input) unzip this and save pdf in the output/pdf folder and XML in the output/XML folder?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to Route the data based upon whether it is PDF or XML and then depending on the route, put it in the proper file. Either you can do this via a RouteOnAttribute if the .pdf or .xml is in one of the attributes or use the RouteOnContent to route upon specific content.

Comment: yes I created a route on attribute but the issue is how can I declare the output folder's path in the put file processor? since I have multiple folders like json , pdf etc..  and only one directory path can be mentioned in the put file processor ? how can I mention multiple output paths in one put file processor.

Comment: What you could do is use an UpdateAttribute to change the filename to the full file path you desire??
Each file has its own unique filename, so if you route it to the appropriate PutFile for each directory, it should work. To have putfile do that, you would need to have it use the filename from the flowfile, which would need to be dynamically set